# Inline align CF7 fields

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Working on CF7 form, but have [one issue](https://infinitistone.co.uk/test-form/) that i need help to resolve. I want label and field to be into same line. I tried already to put `display:inline` into class CSS but doesn't make any change:

```
div.register-form {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
}
```

and this is entire code from my CF7 form:

```html
<div class="register-form">
  <label> Name*
        [text* name-418] </label>

  <label> Last name*
        [text* lastname-418] </label>

  <label> Address*
        [text* address-418] </label>

  <label> Postal Code*
        [text* postalcode-418] </label>

  <label> City*
        [text* city-418] </label>

  <label> Country*
        [select* country-736 "United Kingdom" "Austria" "Belgium" "Bulgaria" "Canada" "Croatia" "Cyprus" "Czech Republic" "Denmark" "Estonia" "Finland" "France" "Germany" "Greece" "Hungary" "Ireland" "Italy" "Latvia" "Lithuania" "Luxembourg" "Malta" "Mexico" "Netherlands" "Poland" "Portugal" "Romania" "Slovakia" "Slovenia" "Spain" "Sweden" "United Arab Emirates" "United Kingdom" "United States of America"] </label>

  <label> Email*
        [email* email-638] </label>

  <label> Phone*
        [tel* telephone-531] </label>

  <label> Phone*
        [tel* telephone-531] </label>

  <label> Batch Number*
        [number* batchnumber1-616] </label>

  <label> Batch Number 2*
        [number* batchnumber2-616] </label>

  <label> Batch Number 3*
        [number* batchnumber3-616] </label>

  <h3>Workshop Information</h3>

  <label> Id/Name*
        [text* idname-418] </label>

  <label> City*
        [text* workshopcity-418] </label>

  <label> Postal Code*
        [text* workshoppostalcode-418] </label>

  <label> Phone*
        [tel* telephone2-531] </label> [acceptance acceptance1-220] Yes, I agree to the terms and conditions of the Warranty and Data Protection Policy.* [/acceptance] [acceptance acceptance2-220] I give my consent to my personal data being processed
  for the execution of commercial, promotional and/or advertising shipments, including communications by email. [/acceptance]

  <small>* Mandatory Fields</small> [submit "Register"]
</div>
```

I want to look like this [one](http://en.compac.es/warranty-3/warranty-registration/) Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to follow the code of the Compac site.

```
.wpcf7 span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

**Remove** the commented

```
.wpcf7-form label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* padding-bottom: 15px; */
    /* border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5; */
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: When add your codes, form goes messed up.. See https://infinitistone.co.uk/test-form/

Comment: I can see it is not good in mobile, you can add media queries to separate them. Else you can use a grid system like the shado answer. You need to add custom styles with regards to that answer. The answer was given based on the site you were trying to copy/inspire from :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with HTML and CSS

In Contact Form 7 form box add your HTML.
Then in your CSS style for sired effect.

```
<div class="col-4"><label>Name*</label></div>
<div class="col-8">[text* name-418]</div>
```

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work?

When you inspect the form, can you see divs?

When you allocate style, are they taking effect?

Have you cleared your cache?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Smart Grid-Layout Responsive Design](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extensions for Contact Form 7.

It has a UI editor that allows you to design a form as a set of columns in a row, with each cell containing a field.